# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir un array en la consola en Java?

Tags: java, array

De esta manera intento imprimir los elementos de un arreglo:

**Mi código:**

```
package Arreglos;

/**
 *
 * @author Jhon Carlos
 */
public class Arreglo {

    public void array(){
        int caja[] = new int[3];

        caja[0] = 3;
        caja[1] = 4;
        caja[2] = 1;
    }

    public void mostrarEnPantalla(){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 3){
        System.out.println(""+caja[i]);
        i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: así como lo tienes no te funciona?

Comment: No veo la función `main()`, corre el programa?

Comment: @AlbertoLopez no, aún no le he creado el `main()`.

Comment: @CryogenicNeo no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principalmente necesitas declarar una función `main()` dentro de la clase que lleva el.mismo nombre que el fichero fuente `.java` que compilarás y ejecutarás posteriormente. Por lo tanto, lo puedes hacer de dos maneras, como si `Arreglo` fuera una clase independiente que la que contiene el método `main()`, ó puedes hacer lo que necesitas en el método `main()` directamente.

**Ejecutar el programa en el método `main()`:**

Para hacer lo que necesitas primero, debes definir el método `main()`, luego hacer uso de un ciclo `for` y de el método `System.out.println()` de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Arreglo 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Declaro el array como una variable.
        int caja[] = new int[3];

        caja[0] = 3; 
        caja[1] = 4; 
        caja[2] = 1;

        // Utilizo un ciclo 'for' para iterar sobre los elementos del array.
        for(int i = 0; i < caja.length; i++)
        {
            // Imprimimos los elementos del array en pantalla.
            System.out.println(""+caja[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

**`Arreglo` es una clase independiente:**

Para imprimirlo debes primero, declarar el método `main()` en una clase con el mismo nombre que el fichero fuente, luego hacer uso de un ciclo `for` y de el método `System.out.println()` dentro de la clase de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Arreglo 
{ 
    // Declaro el array como una variable miembro de la clase Arreglo.
    int caja[] = new int[3];

    // Defino el constructor de la clase, donde defino el contenido de mi arreglo.
    public Arreglo()
    {
        caja[0] = 3; 
        caja[1] = 4; 
        caja[2] = 1; 
    } 

    public void mostrarEnPantalla()
    {
        // Utilizo un ciclo 'for' para iterar sobre los elementos del array.
        for(int i = 0; i < caja.length; i++)
        {
            // Imprimimos los elementos del array en pantalla.
            System.out.println(""+caja[i]);
        } 
    }
}

public class NombreFichero
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Arreglo arr = new Arreglo();
        arr.mostrarEnPantalla();
    }
}
```

Además, he corregido un par de errores que he notado que posee tu código para lograr lo que necesitas.

Primero, invocas el `array` dentro de el método `array()`, permitiendo que solamente exista dentro del método cuando éste se ejecute, por lo tanto, no podrías mostrarlo en el el método `mostrarEnPantalla()`.

Para solucionar este problema he declarado el array `caja[]` como una variable miembro de la clase `Arreglo`:

```
public class Arreglo 
{ 
    int caja[] = new int[3];
    ...
}
```

Luego, defino los elementos del array en el constructor de esta clase:

```
public Arreglo()
    {
        caja[0] = 3; 
        caja[1] = 4; 
        caja[2] = 1; 
    }
```

Una vez sea declarada e inicializada, podrás imprimir sus elementos con el método `mostrarEnPantalla()`.

Por segundo, he cambiado también este ciclo `while`:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 3)
{
    System.out.println(""+caja[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Por este ciclo `for` que te permite iterar sobre los elementos del arreglo sin importar su longitud:

```
for(int i = 0; i < caja.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(""+caja[i]);
    }
```

Si deseas usar un ciclo `while` en vez del `for`, puedes cambiar el código anterior por este:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < caja.length)
{
    System.out.println(""+caja[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me aclaró muchas dudas.

Answer (score 1):

**Imprimir desde el main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int caja[] = new int[3];

        caja[0] = 3;
        caja[1] = 4;
        caja[2] = 1;

        // Con for
        for (int i = 0; i < caja.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(caja[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        // Con while
        int i = 0;
        while (i < caja.length) {
            System.out.println(caja[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

**Imprimir llamando a un método:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int caja[] = new int[3];

        caja[0] = 3;
        caja[1] = 4;
        caja[2] = 1;

        // Imprimir llamando a un método
        mostrarEnPantalla(caja);
    }

    public static void mostrarEnPantalla(int[] caja) {
        System.out.println("(dentro del método)\n");

        // Con for
        for (int i = 0; i < caja.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(caja[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        // Con while
        int i = 0;
        while (i < caja.length) {
            System.out.println(caja[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, por la ayuda de verdad.

Comment: Varios años después, tu respuesta sigue siendo útil. Muchas gracias.